# Is remote partitioning available with JSR-352 under Spring Batch?

Tags: spring, spring-batch, batch-processing, partitioning, jsr352

I would like to configure a JSR-352 batch job for remote partitioning, behind the scenes through configuration, without having to explicitly define the controller/worker in the job definition (which is not supported by the JSR-352 specification anyway).  IBM WebSphere Liberty provides this capability with their "multi-JVM" feature, where you define remote partitioning within the configuration file (server.xml).

I have seen that legacy Spring Batch has the ability to support remote partitioning, but only through an explicit job definition.  I don't want to use legacy Spring Batch.  Instead, I want to build a solution that is portable to Java EE, including IBM Liberty.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want to use legacy Spring Batch. Instead, I want to build a solution that is portable to Java EE, including IBM Liberty.

If you really want a portable solution, you need to define your job in the Job Specification Language of the JSR-352 and launch it with:

```
javax.batch.runtime.BatchRuntime.getJobOperator().start(jobName, properties)
```

Now if JSR-352 does not specify how to define a remote partitioning setup, then you can't get a portable solution for that.

Please note that there are some differences between Spring Batch and JSR-352 which are detailed in the [JSR-352 Support](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/reference/html/jsr-352.html#jsr-352) section. The differences regarding partitioning are documented [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/reference/html/jsr-352.html#jsrPartitioning).

Comment: In the partitioning documentation you referenced, it says "In Spring Batch, partitioned steps are run as manager/worker. Within JSR-352, the same configuration occurs. However, the worker steps do not get official StepExecutions. Because of that, calls to JsrJobOperator#getStepExecutions(long jobExecutionId) will only return the StepExecution for the manager."

With IBM Liberty, you can configure the environment so that partitions are remote.

My question is, if I use the portable JSL syntax in JSR-352, can I still configure the implementation for remote partitioning, outside the job defn?